# Linking to another web page using <a> tag, absolute and relative path concept, I guess

Tags: javascript, html, django, python-3.x

I am trying to link my html files which are under the same folder called "templates". One of the file is called "home.html" which has a link to another html file called "page2.html". The following code works perfectly:

```
<a href="/page2">Click Me</a>
```

But, this gives the url something link this: 127.0.0.1:8000/page2 instead of what I actually want. I want it to be something link this: 127.0.0.1:8000/home/page2. I am making a django web app, but I am new to linking the web pages in the desired form.

Is there a way in which I can achieve the above using html  tag or using javascript or something from the django app?

Is it related to absolute or relative path? If yes, how? Kindly help...

Comment: You are approaching this wrongly. URLs point to views, they do not point to templates.

Comment: I have added it to my urls.py and created a view under the same. Is there a way I can get an appended version of the url from there?

Answer (score 0):

If your current path is for example `127.0.0.1:8000/home` you can to this like that: `<a href="./page2">Click me</a>`
That's becaust `./` is your current directory and `../` is upper directory

EDIT: You should check routing in Django

Comment: It did append it to my URL, but my page2.html did not execute in the browser. How to make my page2.html run after it gets appended in the URL?

Comment: You want 127.0.0.1:8000/home/page2 to run page2.html yes?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have home/html in the path because home.html is a HTML file, not a folder. If you are really keen to have your path like 127.0.0.1:8000/home/page2 , then create a folder called home, move the page2.html into that folder and call it from there. Wouldn't recommend that, though.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing complicated about this. If you want your link to go to "/home/page2", then that's what you should use in the href.

However, there is a better way of doing this in Django; you should use the `{% url %}` tag. Assuming you have defined your URL in urls.py with the name "page2", then do `<a href="{% url "page2" %}">`

Comment: I did that before using href. However, being new to this led me to the same problem as explained above.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If you put "/home/page2" in your href, that is the address you will go to. And if your urls.py defines "page2" as pointing to /home/page2, then `{% url "page2" %}` will resolve to that address as well.

Comment: Currently, I have my page2.html added as a view in my urls.py, which works perfectly something like this: 
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^hello/', hello),
    url(r'^page2/', page2, name='page2'),
]

I want to finally see /home/page2 in my url, sorry for the confusion

Comment: So why haven't you put `r'^home/page2/$'` there then, if that's the address you want to use?